# Issue with custom properties in jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm running into an issue with custom properties while using jQuery UI's autocomplete functionality. For some strange reason, the autocomplete function will not allow me to use the make or id attribute for `ui.item.make` or `ui.item.id`, but is working when it is set to `ui.item.label`.

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvakc/9/) with an example of the issue I am encountering. Here is another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yvakc/8/) of where autocomplete is working, but the difference is only the label property.

Any information why using a custom property doesn't work for me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: rename id to carid and try

Comment: Do you get this via ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply pre-process the list of makes (see the forEach) - IF you get your data via ajax, you could also do something similar.  NOTE:  I also added `return false` to your select so it would not use the value and use your make instead.

```
var carMake = [{
    "make": "Smart",
        "id": '200038885'
}, {
    "make": "Bomb",
        "id": '200038885'
}, {

    "make": "Volkswagen",
        "id": '200000238'
}];

function addlabel(row) {
    row.label = row.make;
    row.value = row.id;
}
carMake.forEach(addlabel);
$("#vehicle_make").autocomplete({
    source: carMake,
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: false,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.make);
        return false;
    }
});
```

EDIT: Ajax data note: to process using ajax data, this would be a method:

```
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data, function (item) {
        return {
                 label: item.make
                 value: item.id,
                 make: item.make,
                 id: item.id
               }
    }))
},
```

Comment: NOTE: I use `this` in the select instead of your selector - appropriate so you only have a single selector to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the default recognized properties only include label and value. If you want to use custom properties you need to implement the custom data property.

Would look something like this:

```
$("#vehicle_make").autocomplete({
    source: carMake,
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: false,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#vehicle_make').val(ui.item.make);
    }
  })
  .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.make+ "<br>" + item.id + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Or via [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvakc/13/)

That should allow you to access the ui.item object with custom properties.
(If you don't want id visible you could just hide it with a hidden field in the list item)

See http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data.

Comment: For some reason the jsfiddle you posted does not work. The only way the autocomplete drop-down appears is when you type the letter b, which is extremely odd.

Comment: The issue is that there are no label and value properties specified, so by default autocomplete tries to search the text box value against those properties. Updated the jsfiddle and should work correctly now. Have to concede here though, @Mark Schultheiss has given an accurate and thorough answer in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) documentation:

> Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
> ...
>
> An array of objects with **label** and **value** properties: [ {
> label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

So, it requires them to be specifically named like this.