# Dialog, datapicker get id

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, dialog

I am somewhat new to javascript and need to integrate couple plugins for one project. Is there a way to get `customer_id` (that was gotten when the dialog window was opened, and suggested by autocomplete) into "Create new job" button location.

I want to close first dialog after user clicks "Create new job" and then open new dialog window, but I want to pass `customer_id` from the first dialog window into second dialog window. There might be some dialog and autocomplete interaction that I might not understand, I just can't get `customer_id` before I call `new_job()` function.

```
$(function() {
 $( "#dialog-name" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
})});

function customer_funct(){  
$( "#dialog-name" ).dialog( "open" )

$(function() {
var name = $( "#name" );

  $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
  source: "suggest_name.php",
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    var customer_id = ui.item.customer_id;  

// I am able to get customer_id here,
//now I need to pass it to the function below.
}  
});



$( "#dialog-name" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 500,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Create new job": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        cust_name = (name.val());


// is there any way to get "customer_id" at this location 
// before I call new_job() function after the user selects customer
// from the database and clicks "Create new job"?

        new_job(customer_id, cust_name);

    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Modify your code snippet better please. Check if it looks right in the preview after doing copy-paste, before posting it. Also create a jsfiddle.net fiddle, so we can see your html and debug easier.

Comment: Sorry, edited how it is presented on stackoverflow.com now, looks better

Comment: Can you also post your HTML code as well. If possible, create a fiddle at [link](jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I answer the question myself after some thinking. If someone else is working on jQuery autocomplete and dialog interaction, and if you need to open the new dialog window (in new_job(customer_id))with the id value from the previous dialog window and close that previous dialog window on success:

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog-name" ).dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
})});


function customer_funct(){

$( "#dialog-name" ).dialog( "open" )



$(function() {
 var name = $( "#name" );

  $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
    source: "suggest_name.php",
    minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
      var customer_id = ui.item.customer_id;
    new_job(customer_id);   
    $(this).val(''); return false;
  }  
});



$( "#dialog-name" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 500,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Create new job": function() {

        alert('Please select customer or click "Add New" customer');

         },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
  });
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the select event ui parameter only contains a "label" and "value" property

[JQuery UI Autocomplete Success Event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)

In order to access a custom property you would need to explicitly add it after you retrieve your data via an ajax call. Similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908247/issue-with-custom-properties-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete/15908679#15908679).